# arima.errors() shows different errors on same model when using arima() and Arima()

Tags: r, time-series

I am fitting a regression with ARMA errors using the base R function `arima()` and the `Arima()` function from the `forecast` package.

The estimated coefficients from both are identical. My problem comes from using `arima.errors()` on these two models, and using `tsdisplay()` to view these structural residuals (that is, the residuals straight from the regression, before any ARMA model is fit on them). These ARMA errors (and their corresponding ACFs, PACFs) are different between the two, and I don't know why. Even more curious is that the final residuals from both are in fact the same, which would make me think the structural residuals would have to be the same. I have put a MWE below.

```
library('forecast')
data(usconsumption, package='fpp')

fit1 = arima(usconsumption[ ,1], xreg=usconsumption[ ,2], order=c(2,0,0))
tsdisplay(arima.errors(fit1), main="ARIMA errors, arima function") # not the same as the other


fit2 = Arima(usconsumption[,1], xreg=usconsumption[,2], order=c(2,0,0))
dev.new()
tsdisplay(arima.errors(fit2), main="ARIMA errors, Arima function") # not the same as the other


View(cbind(resid(fit1), resid(fit2))) # final residuals are the same
```

Note this example is from https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arima.errors` looks in the object that has been passed to find the `xreg` information. If it finds it, it subtracts out the regression part of the model and returns the ARMA errors. If it doesn't find the `xreg` information, it assumes you have a pure ARIMA model and returns the original data.

It should always work correctly with objects created with `Arima`, but it may not work correctly if you use `arima` instead. Note that the book says to use `Arima`. There is no reason ever to use `arima`.

In this case, it does not find the `xreg` information in `fit1` and so it returns the `usconsumption[,1]` data.

I will see if I can modify `arima.errors` to at least send back a warning in cases like this. But if you just use `Arima` all the time, and never use `arima`, this problem will not arise.

Comment: The latest version of the package on github (https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast) will now find the `xreg` info in the first example.